# Angular Selenium requests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

ok I'm trying to tell my java selenium program to wait for all angular type requests to finish loading, this one is special:

`<span _ngcontent-xse-c0 class = "loading" hidden> </span`

try it with:

`private loading = By.xpath ("/ html / body / app-root / main / app-home-spreadsheet / spinner-app / span");`

`WebDriverWait waitLoading = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);
waitLoading .until (ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated (loading));`

`waitLoading.until (ExpectedConditions.not (ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable (loading)));`

but I can't get it to work, selenium ignora todas las esperas, las da por hechas, aunque el elemento aun este presente para selenium es como si ya hubiera pasado e intenta ejecutar la siguiente accion, por ejemplo un click

y ocurre este error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element `<mdb-select _ngcontent-jbv-c4="" class="colorful-select dropdown-primary
>   ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="idClaseAportante" id="idClaseAportante" mdbvalidate="">...</mdb-select>` is not clickable at point (508, 426). Other element would receive the click: `<span _ngcontent-jbv-c0="" >class="loading"></span>`

I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Can you add some more information on exactly what happens, errors etc.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using along with the error message you get when run. You are missing a Type (`By`) in line 1 and your locator is named `loading` but you are referencing `spiner` (spinner?) as a variable that is not defined anywhere in the posted code. Thanks.